# How to toggle each div with toggle() function in a dynamic php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm minimizing the visual display of my list blocks, and I want to use toggle with a button to hide the content that I dont want to appear by default.

I nearly do it with the next() jquery property, but this forces me to put the button in the previous element of the content that I want hide (thats why it's called NEXT), but I want to hide the class content two or three class elements below. How can I do it? I tried with siblings() but didn't work.

```
        if ( tribe_get_cost() ) : 
            $event_cost='<!-- Event Cost -->
            <div class="ect-event-cost">
                <span>'.tribe_get_cost($event_id, true ).'</span>
            </div>';
            endif;

            $event_title='<a class="ect-event-url" href="'.esc_url( tribe_get_event_link()).'" rel="bookmark">'. get_the_title().'</a>';


            $event_content='<button class="btn1" class="button">More..</button><!-- Event Content --><div class="p1"><div class="ect-event-content">';
              $event_content.=tribe_events_get_the_excerpt($event_id, wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) );

            $event_content.='<a href="'.esc_url( tribe_get_event_link($event_id) ).'" class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">'.esc_html__( 'Find out more', 'the-events-calendar' ).' &raquo;</a></div></div></div>';
    /*
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".p1").hide();

    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".p1").toggle()
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know why `.next()` doesn't work using `$(this).next(".p1").toggle()` ?

Because you have a comment in between: `<!-- Event Content -->`.

It would work instead. A comment tag **is** an element. Just remove it and try again.

Since you use PHP... Is suggest you to place that kind of comment in some PHP comment like this: `<?php // Event Content ?>`, so it does not show in the rendered page on the client side.

Comment: Yeah, I inserted after the comment and it's work with next(), but i want that it searches and jumping the "comment" element and the other elements that may have, and search it for the nearest p1. I tried with children() but didn't work, with parents() it works but ascendant, I want it to make descendant too.

Comment: I'm not sure to get it... But if you **really** want to keep that HTML comment, try `$(this).next().next(".p1").toggle()` or `$(this).parent().find(".p1").toggle()`... something like.

Comment: Or `$(this).siblings(".p1").toggle()`... There is many options... ;) -- The key is to be logic in understanding the structure you are dealing with.

Comment: I used `$(this).parent().find(".p1-img").toggle();` (another class that I want to toggle too) to find the nearest p1-img parent and toggle it but didn't work. If i use `$(this).parents().find(".p1-img").toggle();` (see the "parents" difference), it work's but it's toggle all the parent's, not only the first one. **The parent that i want is 5 levels above the <button> tag.**

Comment: To look for a parent of a n level or unknown level (but a parent for sure, else it won't work), use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: `$(this).closest(".p1-img").toggle();` didn't work for me. Finally I used: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".p1-img").show();` I dont know if is a smart way but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: So the parent you need is not the 5th level above, but the 4th. This works too: `$(this).parents().eq(4).find(".p1-img").show();` --- Notice the **s** of [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).